# Is exchanging Indian currency at premium legal?

Tags: indian-penal-code, currency

Is exchanging/selling Indian currency notes, like the ones which have special sequences numbers or are extra old (antique), at premium legally allowed?

Comment: Why would it not be legal?

Answer (score 0):

Appears to be legal; many people sell antique Indian currency or currency with special numbers on eBay: http://www.ebay.in/sch/?_sacat=11116

And the Indian Coinage Act of 2011 does not appear to outlaw it: https://www.rbi.org.in/Scripts/OccasionalPublications.aspx?head=Indian%20Coinage%20Act

Comment: "People do it on eBay" isn't much support for "it appears to be legal".

Comment: eBay quicky removes illegal items, and that's the East Indian version of eBay, so I assume it is monitored. And I say _appears_ because IANAL, and this site is not legal advice, even though many new and low rep users assume it is.

Comment: Fair enough. Proving the negative is usually a difficult question without explicit legislation to call on.